# Notepad++ - How to mass copy numbers at the beginning of lines to another part of each line?

Tags: regex, replace, copy, notepad++

So I'm looking for a faster way to mass reformat some files for a game.

I have code like this:

```
84045 = {
    name = Sam
    dynasty = 3
    dna = kfsdiofjsoidfj
    culture = example
    religion = example
    martial = 10
    diplomacy = 10
    stewardship = 10
    intrigue = 10
    learning = 10
    add_trait = trait
    add_trait = trait
    add_trait = trait

    father = 84042
    1395.6.7 = {birth = ""}
    1449.6.7 = {death = ""}
}
```

What I need relates to this part:

```
    1395.6.7 = {birth = ""}
    1449.6.7 = {death = ""}
```

So I have hundreds of these entries. What I want is for the numbers like "1395.6.7" to be mass copied and entered into the quote marks, with the result like this:

```
    1395.6.7 = {birth = "1395.6.7"}
    1449.6.7 = {death = "1449.6.7"}
```

How can I do this in Notepad++ (or potentially some other easy way)?

Comment: Alt+click and drag down in the column right before the quotation mark. Drag all the way down until you have a cursor in each line. The you can use shift+ctrl and the arrow keys to select the text you want to copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `([\d.]+) = {(?:bir|dea)th = "\K(?="})`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
([\d.]+)        # group 1, 1 or more digit or dot
 = {            # literally
(?:bir|dea)     # non capture group, bir OR dea
th = "          # literally
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
(?="})          # positive lookahead, make sure we have a quote and closing bracket after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do this in Notepad++ (or potentially some other easy way)?

You can replace all `((\d+\.\d+\.\d+) = {...th = ")"}` with `\1\2"}` in *Search mode* *Regular expression*.